# SQLDatasource parameters problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

Why if i use the following instruction in the code behind:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["page"].DefaultValue = "0";
```

I get 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

'?

Comment: Is `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters` valid (!= null)?? Is `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["page"]` valid (!= null)?? This is just very basic debugging....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only two objects involves in that single statement are (bold)

**SqlDataSource1**.SelectParameters["page"].DefaultValue

**SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["page"]**.DefaultValue

So one of them must be null.  When looking at this together with your previous question, it is because you have not yet added the "page" parameter to `SqlDataSource1`.

Answer (score 1):

Either your `SqlDataSource` object is null or its `SelectParameters` collection doesn't have an entry for "page". Check that you have defined that select parameter appropriately.

Comment: Parameter must be one of Control, Cookie, Form, Profile, QueryString, Session or Route. Since I didn't create a session variable or a cookie I didn't try those. I tried the others and they all failed. How do I create the parameter?